# python: beautiful soup extracting info

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to parse HTML as follows:

```
html_content2 ="""
<h3 style="cear: both;">
<abbr title="European Union">EU</abbr>Investment</h3>
<div class="conditions">
<p>bla bla bla
</p>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0;">
<span class="amount">66000 €</span>
</p>"""
```

I would like to extract the amount of money and the code I have is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_content=html_content1
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
t3 = soup.find(lambda tag:tag.name=="h3" and ": Investment").find_next_sibling().find_next_sibling("p").find("span").contents
print(t3)
```

The intention here is the following:
get h3 tag WITH text Investment and from there get next sibling and another next sibling with tag p then span and get the contents

In this previous code I dont how to include the word "Investiment" in the lambda function.
I tried:

```
tag.name=="h3" and tag.contents==": Investment"
```

this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda tag: tag.name == "h3" and "Investment" in tag.text`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = """
<h3 style="cear: both;">
<abbr title="European Union">EU</abbr>Investment</h3>
<div class="conditions">
<p>bla bla bla
</p>
</div>
<p style="margin-bottom: 0;">
<span class="amount">66000 €</span>
</p>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

amount = (
    soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "h3" and "Investment" in tag.text)
    .find_next("span", class_="amount")
    .text
)
print(amount)
```

Prints:

```
66000 €
```

---

You can use CSS selectors too:

```py
amount = soup.select_one("h3:-soup-contains('Investment') ~ * .amount").text
print(amount)
```

Prints:

```
66000 €
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with just one statement (`select`) using [CSS selectors](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains) :

```py
# t3selector = ....
t3 = soup.select_one(t3selector).get_text(strip=True)
```

where

```py
t3selector = 'h3:-soup-contains("Investment") ~ * .amount'
```

if you just want the text from an element with a class `amount` inside a sibling of a `h3` containing "Investment", but if you want exactly

> get h3 tag WITH text Investment and from there get next sibling and another next sibling with tag p then span and get the contents

you'll need a slightly more specific selector

```py
t3selector = 'h3:-soup-contains("Investment") + * + p span'
```

( if the `span` must be a child [direct descendant] of `p`, then end with `p > span` )

---

And the correct way to utilize `lambda` here would be something like:

```py
t3 = soup.find(
    lambda tag:tag.name=="h3" and "Investment" in tag.text
).find_next_sibling("p").find("span").get_text(strip=True)
```

but I think the selector method is better because this has too many calls - if any of the `find`s return `None`, an error will be raised.

---

Actually, even with the selector, it's safest to use

```py
t3 = soup.select_one(t3selector)
if t3 is not None: t3 = t3.get_text(strip=True)
```